# How add Html code with script in Indesign?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, adobe-indesign

I managed to add this working code in indesign :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
          ([['X', '1'],
          ['Bien',     900000],
          ['Honoraires notariés', 67500],
          ['Travaux',  300000],
          ['Mobilier', 67500],
          ['Honoraires Hikin\'Vest', 100500]
        ]);
        var options = {
          is3D: true,
          colors: ['#4c96d7', '#cf1717', '#168200', '#f7e031', '#c49a6c'],
          chartArea: {width: '86%', height: '86%', left:'40', bottom:'04'},
          legend: {position: 'in'},
                    slices: {  4: {offset: 0.2},
                    1: {offset: 0.2},
                     2: {offset: 0.2},
                      3: {offset: 0.2},
          theme: 'maximized',
          },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 350px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this one doesn't work, can you help me ?

This code  was generated on https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-albums.

If it's not possible can you tell me how embed a slideshow with google Drive or Google photos in InDesign.

I use "Publish Online" in InDesign.

Thank you very much.

```html
<html>
  <head>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/publicalbum@latest/embed-ui.min.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pa-gallery-player-widget" style="width:100%; height:480px; display:none;"
      data-link="https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM8qglM9SYDwhbTlTsBwzMFNnUy3ae_MhZ6G0MrT2R3M208j2EeB6EOiSj7Q6BUgg?key=aGZmTThnOHZIS0NzSlZaaWwtZEtJZkRnUjlXVjBn"
      data-title="Bondy"
      data-description="8 new photos added to shared album"
      data-background-color="#ffffff">
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lpIrmwAAeI-p6U3aI4dsEfGTBAGIFueRj5B-s-5MiDT85gHXGYYgEh-JDDs2Ctdor2wj-JHJYmTbhBT9sqDlcfOwOseTPFrVsZWqdWqMss7ddUhAzFfeytr0M12MUX9GPGK9bekgiA=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/6kQS6AXg7Lu0u1GgfcZU7WwAhVcjkctwjChyJ4QgpVRp9pssLWMGcOoXfu7iaEr32P6GhS1ePayrHJeJEPcZTKCf_FeQMkx5j2bcBL-rT79fR1HOff8RmuV1vF-e-3mkdWyDu8mnpQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OVm-Eja_ulFg2RW-JjDmhmOZH7qx343wTfqP4WAHyLSvgJsGhtSBW1Og8VG7pFa-WPDqvW1xKKb4PHK_WoPpXq9MhNTtzT2ITH7oe0mkRMO3C6zHjRbedZNY2w8VpAZUVeuEG47qqA=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HO9K0UCj1VUhDe9bJEomkVt6So2rKnwT_V6Il9Nx734bONRRi1QU34aCxPM-SJPXi3Lfp_K5zQcu5CcHFws4bwq6yQKvROEO7KISdewHfYBvud-GY22tm4kC3yGmxbC21l0nIr4O_g=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nayFhxGXP6pCAstQlKYGbd662JjpBoeA15xyF5rVoXhefkeuYeAQrB-Pq0AkPBbiFOgdeGcbCOSdeV2RCe-tQrA5ufJ1muw5oHUr01CtCRNx-9B5tI_h1lzUkC0z3tWOrfMQvp4SqA=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dmQ4e_p0Z5kDRNw5R2RuH1XMQDPuEaUThXGp3rPiroV6nYwhIktZe5Zlc1olbZywP0YLJBDZJSoyL76zNTbGJIvpXyUE4GFhanvAP_MCrL_ZLv9ayNX47yYba4iPlK_glqkui_KGVw=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LVHXYLdL3kcDIT8TBIC7jfwsKCZKVYpdAaa49PhTG8wgziuC36N1OoFaQEC_R4GHZp-YJ-VO8fLU5P6zarsatwbikOVrqlqxDMKh6y-_2-rlIzGpb6bxbm4LFUDS3pUJKPKG-TVVWw=w1920-h1080"></object>
      <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2Um38iEfoYKBoe6l4_YDiYNNsnnz_4sBm4FF-ogxveFxNJOkMIA-7kcHk8c5WA3-9yUc3670lh_v2ZoFBkh84r4_nitdyg9kJ3tuUUJ1hdFk8D5cvLBBdHcX2jIa-ia_rAjLr-Y3ug=w1920-h1080"></object>
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it looks for me as the task that can not be accomplished this way at all. I think you have to download all these photos on your HDD first. Then you can place them in your InDesign document (manually of via some script). This online generated HTML code has nothing to do with InDesign and its ExtedScript.

InDesing has a tool to publish documents online, but all these documents (and all linked images) should be stored locally first. As far as I know.